# Large Lego Ninjago package, no box and no instructions, many red and black pieces

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

These packages were all unopened. Only package number five came with a Ninjago mini figure.

Could someone possibly be able to get me the box information so I can look up the instructions!

[image: picture with bag 5] [image: Picture with bag 5] [image: Bag 5]
[image: picture with bag 6 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiJ2q.jpg)![picture with bag 6][image: bag 6 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzOVx.jpg)![picture with bag 8](http picture with bag][image: bag 8 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYDS7.jpg)![picture with bag 7][image: picture with box 7][image: Bag 7][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the red quarter domes, I'm fairly certain the bricks are from this set:
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70615-1
[image]

Comment: https://media3.webcollage.net/e7591287200999f3ebb67aeb1d0fe6a13bc25874?response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIIE5CHZ4PRWSLYKQ&Expires=1893517796&Signature=t%2BOpkHf7lQPzrB3%2FPzdgFauejow%3D   fire disk match too

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Awesome! On the instruction booklet, the Pieces i have match bags five through eight I just don’t have bags one through four do you know of a website that sells just certain bags out of boxes

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of such website and I think it unlikely to exist. You could probably create a "wanted list" on bricklink if you have the time and patience to go through the inventory list and strike out the pieces you have. Not sure if buying the missing pieces on bricklink will eventually be cheaper than buying the set new or secondhand